# Implementing complex MAX function in Spring Boot/JPA query language

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot-jpa

Spring Boot here using JPA/Hibernate and `CrudRepository` impls for managing persistence to my DB tables.

I have the following MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS price_scarcity_configs (
    price_scarcity_config_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    price_scarcity_config_ref_id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    price_scarcity_config_version BIGINT NOT NULL,
    price_scarcity_config_updated_on DATETIME NOT NULL,
    price_scarcity_config_fizz INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_price_scarcity_configs PRIMARY KEY (price_scarcity_config_id),

    CONSTRAINT uc_price_scarcity_configs_ref_id_and_version UNIQUE (price_scarcity_config_ref_id, price_scarcity_config_version)
);
```

These records will be **versioned** and different versions of the "same" record will all share the same `price_scarcity_config_ref_id`. Hence 2+ records can have the same `price_scarcity_config_ref_id` but will have two distinct different versions.

I'm also using the following JPA/Hibernate entity to model it:

```
// Uses Lombok annotations to generate getters/setters, etc.

@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String refId;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "price_scarcity_configs")
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "price_scarcity_config_id")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "refId", column = @Column(name = "price_scarcity_config_ref_id"))
})
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class PriceScarcityConfiguration extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "price_scarcity_config_version")
    private Long version;

    @Column(name = "price_scarcity_config_updated_on")
    private Date updatedOn;

    @Column(name = "price_scarcity_config_fizz")
    private Integer fizz;

}
```

I am now trying to write the `PriceScarcityConfigurationRepository` and need a fairly sophisticated query. Given a `refId`, I need to find the record who matches that ref id **and has the highest/max version number**. The raw SQL query to perform this is:

```
select
  *
from
  price_scarcity_configs pcs
inner join
  (
    SELECT
      price_scarcity_config_ref_id,
      MAX(price_scarcity_config_version) as max_ver
    FROM
      price_scarcity_configs
    group by
      price_scarcity_config_ref_id
  ) t
on
  t.price_scarcity_config_ref_id = pcs.price_scarcity_config_ref_id 
  and
  t.max_ver = pcs.price_scarcity_config_version;
```

Given my repository and using JPA/Hibernate's built-in query language/annos, how do I implement this query?

```
public interface PriceScarcityConfigurationRepository extends CrudRepository<PriceScarcityConfiguration,Long> {

    @Query("FROM PriceScarcityConfiguration WHERE ??? HOW TO IMPLEMENT THE ABOVE QUERY HERE ???")
    PriceSheetConfiguration fetchLatestVersionByRefId(@Param("refId") String refId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following query instead and use `setMaxResults(1)`

```
FROM PriceScarcityConfiguration p WHERE p.refId = :refId ORDER BY p.version DESC
```

Or simply use the Spring Data notation

```
List<PriceSheetConfiguration> findFirstByRefIdOrderByVersionDesc(String refId);
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian (+1) -- where would I `setMaxResults(1)` though (for the first solution)?

Comment: When you have an entity manager you use `entityManager.createQuery("FROM PriceScarcityConfiguration p WHERE p.refId = :refId ORDER BY p.version DESC").setParameter("refId", refId).setMaxResults(1).getResultList()`

Comment: Inside the `PriceScarcityConfigurationRepository` interface, can I define an interface method and put that `"FROM PriceScarcityConfiguration..."` string inside an `@Query` anno?

Comment: I don't think so, you will have to inject an entity manager and execute the query manually. Is the spring data notion not working for you? `List<PriceSheetConfiguration> findFirstByRefIdOrderByVersionDesc(String refId);`

Comment: I will try it but would be weary of using it unless I can find some solid documentation on how it works...I tried googling "spring data notation" and surprisingly nothing cropped up, just a bunch of guides to how spring _annotations_ work. Can you point me in the right direction? I'd like to read up on how spring data notation works first! Thanks again!

Comment: Here it is: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Comment: Ahhh ok looks like these are officially called **JPA Query Methods**, thanks! Let me play around with these today/tomorrow and I'll get back to you! Thanks again